# How to open windows 7 file explorer window in the position of a current file explorer window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I regularly use the Ctrl+N hotkey to launch a new file explorer window, but this new window opens 'far' from the currently open explorer window. What I prefer is that the new window open exactly overlapping the current/prior window.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you open a new file explorer window (whether you use the shortcut/hotkey or not) it will always open with the last used window settings. So an easy way to do it is:

**Method 1**

1. Open a new file explorer window.
2. Resize and position it however you prefer.
3. Close the window (so the settings get saved as the last used settings).
4. Open a new explorer window, and you should see it open exactly as the one you closed.
5. If step 4 went well, use the hotkey/shortcut and it should work.

**Method 2**

Open a new window, right click on taskbar and click on *Cascade windows*, now simply use hotkey/shortcut and the new window should be right on top.

**Note:** I'm on Windows 10 OS and it works, so you'll have to try.

Comment: It often opens at the same position/size, other times not. It seems random. Guess i'll have to live with it.

Comment: Well, I found another way. Having your windows with any position/size, right click on the taskbar and click on _Cascade windows_, it will literally put all of the opened windows in that way. After this use the hotkey/shortcut and it should work. **Don't give up just yet :D**.